# ServiceNow compare environment and tags

Tags: servicenow

I have two related questions :

1. Is there a way in servicenow such that I can compare two different environments? For e.g. I have 10 servers listed for a Business Service, now I would like to compare Server 1 and Server 2 and find out if they are same and matching all configuration data.
2. Is there a way I can compare two tags ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not included enough information for me to even ask questions about what you're talking about.

You want to compare two environments. Environments of what? ServiceNow instances? How are they connected? Where is this data stored?

Say you have ten servers listed... you want to compare them... okay, where are they located? Are they in servicenow?

you want to compare two tags... what tags? where? in servicenow? are you talking about asset tags? are they stored on SN?

What are you even talking about?

Comment: Here are more information related to this: I've these ten servers listed in servicenow, which are actually discovered by servicenow. If I open any one these servers it will give me details about that particular server like IP Address, OS Version, Software Installed, CPU Type, Network Adapters, Running Process etc. Now my question is, if there is a way I can compare two servers such that I can caught if the two servers I'm comparing has different OS version (Just an example). Hope this clarify